# Get output data from Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I created a Matlab GUI called comparison using GUIDE but until now I'm not managed to retrieve the output without get error. My code is:

```
function varargout = comparison(varargin)
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @comparison_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @comparison_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end

function comparison_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.Receiver=zeros(1,15);
handles.Signal=zeros(1,4);
handles.CCCcombination=zeros(1,5);
handles.FilterFlag=0;

handles.output = hObject;

guidata(hObject, handles);

uiwait(handles.figure1);

function varargout = comparison_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;

uiresume(handles.figure1);
delete(handles.figure1);

function Close_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.CCCcombination=zeros(1,5);
handles.Signal=zeros(1,4);
handles.Receiver=zeros(1,5);
handles.FilterFlag=0;
s.Receiver=handles.Receiver;
s.Signal=handles.Signal;
s.CCCcombination=handles.CCCcombination;
s.FilterFlag=handles.FilterFlag;
handles.output=s;
guidata(hObject, handles);
comparison_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

When run `comparison`, my output is the following:

```
s=comparison
ans = 
          Receiver: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
            Signal: [0 0 0 0]
    CCCcombination: [0 0 0 0 0]
        FilterFlag: 0
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in comparison>comparison_OutputFcn (line 106)
varargout{1} = handles.output;
```

Comment: What is the `Close_button_Callback`? A pushbutton meant to close the GUI? Do you have any code in the `figure1_CloseRequestFcn`?

Comment: Yes, `Close_button_Callback` is the pushbutton to close the GUI and I haven't code in `figure1_CloseRequestFcn`

Comment: Ok is there a reason for that? I mean could you delete the pushbutton and use the `CloseRequest_Fcn` instead (i.e. it would execute when you manually close the figure)? Actually can you tell what is your GUI used for? Do you want to retrieve the output when you press a specific button for instance ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to retrieve the output when my Close button is pressed. comparison GUI is called from another GUI. I need to get some value from comparison gui, only when the user pushes the button Close to confirm the finish of the executed operation. I would like to get some value  as my output shown but without got any errors.